# Custom header and footer in an iPhone table view

Tags: interface-builder, uitableview

I'm trying to implement something just like the HeaderFooter sample code that [apple provides](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/HeaderFooter/Introduction/Intro.html):

Unfortunately they used Interface Builder to do most of the work here, and I'm beginning to see that interface builder is the hardest thing to deal with in iPhone development.

My table works fine, but the header and footer aren't there at all. My question is how can I make it work.

My code is identical to Apple's, with a few name changes:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // headerView
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.headerView.frame.size.height);
    self.headerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.headerView.frame = newFrame;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.headerView;   // note this will override UITableView's 'sectionHeaderHeight' property

    // set up the table's footer view based on our UIView 'myFooterView' outlet
    newFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, self.footerView.frame.size.height);
    self.footerView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.footerView.frame = newFrame;
    self.tableView.tableFooterView = self.footerView;   // note this will override UITableView's 'sectionFooterHeight' property

//...
```

The problem must be in my xib file, but the sample file has one giant nib that defines everything, all the way back to the window so I can't use that. I had to make my own.

I started with a uitableviewcontroller and nib and added header and footer views views to the nib.

I connected them to their respective IBOutlets in the table view controller subclass.

The delegate and datasource are connected and all the table cells work fine.

What did I forget? Why isn't it making the header and footer?

Follow up question:
How can I learn how to use IB? I try to avoid it, but sometimes I can't. It seems really poorly documented.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when I used `initWithNibNamed:` to create the `view`. I'm not really sure why. It seems to use the `.nib` when I use `initWithStyle:`. I have to admit, I'm still fuzzy on the relationship between `UIViewControllers` and `.nib`s…